# JSlider problems with ticks

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, jslider

I'm trying to use `JSlider` for the first time and I tried consulting [How to Use Sliders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html) to learn the basics.
But when I try to make the ticks appear like this:

```
 sliderInterior = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL,-100,100,0);
 sliderInterior.setMinorTickSpacing(5);
 sliderInterior.setMajorTickSpacing(10);
 sliderInterior.setPaintTicks(true);
```

The ticks just don't appear. What's the problem?

**EDIT**
Did a SSCCE as requested. The problem remains, a JSlider with no ticks at all.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package Interface;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JSlider;

    public class JSliderTicks extends javax.swing.JDialog {

    public JSliderTicks(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
        super(parent, modal);
        initComponents();

        slider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL,0,10,5);
        slider.setMinorTickSpacing(1);
        slider.setMajorTickSpacing(2);
        slider.setPaintTicks(true);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, slider);

        setVisible(true);
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        slider = new javax.swing.JSlider();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(85, 85, 85)
                .addComponent(slider, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(115, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(117, 117, 117)
                .addComponent(slider, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(160, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JSliderTicks.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JSliderTicks.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JSliderTicks.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JSliderTicks.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the dialog */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JSliderTicks dialog = new JSliderTicks(new javax.swing.JFrame(), true);
                dialog.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                });
                dialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JSlider slider;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

I only changed the constructor since I'm using JDialog Form and the rest is implemented automatically.

I just noticed, if I use JOptionPane the JSlider works fine but in the JDialog it stays unaltered.

Comment: Works fine for me.  What problems are you having?

Comment: The JSlider just stays the same with no ticks at all, I tried adding labels and stayed the same. What could be the problem? Btw I'm using a JDialog Fom if that's important.

Comment: That's not really am SSCCE, that's a constructor

Comment: I didn't put the rest since it's generated automatically by the JDialog Form.

Comment: Using the code you posted, I see ticks whether it is Nimbus PLAF or the default PLAF.  Admittedly there are fewer ticks than in the screenshot I posted, because the slider has a smaller range, but they are definitely there.  Can you post (or link to) a screenshot of what *you* see?

Comment: Here it is: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=15ckec6&s=5#.UsyvR_R1yrM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening is that you're creating an `new JSlider` in the consructor, when one is already create in the `initComponents` and added. Also, the `JOptionPane`, messes it up also, as a component can only be added to one parent container. I removed the `JOptionPane` and re-initialization of the `JSlider` and it works. I also set the `minimum`, `maximum`, and `value` accordingly.

```
    initComponents();

    //slider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL,0,10,5);
    slider.setMinimum(0);
    slider.setMaximum(10);
    slider.setValue(5);
    slider.setMinorTickSpacing(1);
    slider.setMajorTickSpacing(2);
    slider.setPaintTicks(true);

    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, slider);

    //setVisible(true);                              <<---- already set visible
```

Comment: Aw that was indeed the problem. I don't know how I missed that. Thanks mate!

Comment: I also set the min, max, and value.

Comment: Note that is one of the (many) reasons we recommend posting an SSCCE.  The problem is often not where you think it is.  ;)  As a side note, your final 'SSCCE' was not an SSCCE, since it did it correctly, and it was therefore not an 'Example' of the problem!

Comment: I'm thinking that the properties could all be set from the properties pane in the GUI Builder. If you highlight the `JSlider` and go to the properties pane on the right, you should see a list of all the properties of the `JSlider` that can be changed. I'm sure all the ones listed above should be in the list of properties. Learning to use that pane will prevent a lot of these headaches :)

Comment: Didn't think that at the time. Will remember that the next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It works just fine in this SSCCE.

[image: Slider Ticks]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class SliderTicks {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JSlider sliderInterior = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, -100, 100, 0);
                sliderInterior.setMinorTickSpacing(5);
                sliderInterior.setMajorTickSpacing(10);
                sliderInterior.setPaintTicks(true);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sliderInterior);
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using a JDialog Form. Does that matter or change anything ?

Comment: @user3127568 No - From the sounds of it you are either using a `null` layout or sizing the frame manually..

Comment: Already edited the question, with a SSCCE. Sorry about the first reply!

Comment: I did. It works fine when I show the JSlider in the JOptionPane. In the JDialog for some reason doesn't.